# how to use Office Scripts in power automate?

Tags: power-automate, office-scripts

The documentation says that office scripts works with power automate.
Does anyone know how to run an office script using power automate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We just added some new tutorials for using Office Scripts with Power Automate. You should find the information you're looking for here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/tutorials/excel-power-automate-manual

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is as followed.

- Create a new environment in power automate
- specify the environment as a united states Preview environment
- create flow
- you should now see Run Script appear

Comment: As of today, this is actually now possible in a standard environment—here’s a blog post where you can learn more: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-support-for-office-scripts-in-the-excel-online-business-connector/

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel already stated, now you can use an action in Microsoft Power Automate to run an Office Script:
[image: screenshot Power Automate Action run script]

The blog post describes in detail how to use this Action: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-support-for-office-scripts-in-the-excel-online-business-connector/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example of using "Run Script" action in Power Automate.

This simple script delete all rows of the excel. First, go to Automate tab in your excel -> All Script -> New Script. Write it down your script and save it.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let myTable = workbook.getTable("Your_Table_Name");
let rowCount = myTable.getRowCount();
myTable.deleteRowsAt(0, rowCount);}
```

Replace "Your_Table_Name" with you table name and save it as "Delete All Rows".

In Power Automate, add action "Run Script" and select Location, File Name and Script Name as shown in example.
[image]

Once you run this flow, it will run your excel script as well and delete all the rows.