# Call Office script from outside of MS Excel WebApp

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-365, office-scripts

In the Excel WebApp (Office 365) it is possible to place Office Scripts via the "Automate" tab, which is using the JavaScript-syntax and which could automate excel like a VBA-macro, but for the excel WebApp  (Screenshot).

(How) is it possible to call an Excel-Office-Script function from outside the excel WebApp?
One scenario would be having the Excel Webapp nested like in a frame and calling the office script from outside the frame or
another scenario would be to just call an office-script via the browser console.

[image: Screenshot of the excel webapp with office-scripts-code-editor opened]

Answer (score 3):

The offline execution of Office Scripts is possible through Power Automate platform, which allows end-users to automate their Excel related tasks as part of a larger flow. An Office Script can be invoked against any Excel file on OneDrive/SharePoint site and data can be passed to a script and script can return data out of Excel that can then be integrated across other apps.

See here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/scripts/develop/power-automate-integration

Other scenarios you site such as ability to invoke Office Script via browser console or from other parts of Excel app is not supported. There is one aspect that is of interest to us, which is to allow web add-ins to invoke Office Script. Please feel free to add feature asks here: https://excel.uservoice.com/

Examples of offline scenarios with Office Scripts:

```
1. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/Cross-Reference-and-formatting-two-Excel-files-using-Office/td-p/728535
2. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/Excel-and-Microsoft-Forms-integration-using-Office-Scripts/td-p/728183
```

Comment: See this question (and answer) for further help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62467182/how-to-use-office-scripts-in-power-automate